# Finding Interior and Closure in a Topology(Am I right?)

Tags: general-topology

If $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T})$ is a topology, $\mathcal{T}$ := {$U \in \mathbb{R} : U = \emptyset \lor (\mathbb{R}- U)$ is a finite set}, Let $A = [0,1]$. Find the closure and interior of $A$.

for questions like this, I always starts to find the closed sets and open sets for the topology.

A set $F$ is closed iff $\mathbb{R} - F$ open iff $(\mathbb{R} - F = \emptyset$     or $\mathbb{R} - (\mathbb{R} - F)$ finite) iff ($\mathbb{R} = F$ or $F$ finite)

the closed sets are the whole space $\mathbb{R}$ (as always) plus all finite sets. The smallest closed sets that contains $A$ must only be $\mathbb{R}$ for no finite set contains $A$ ($A$ is an infinite set ?). Hence, $clo(A)$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

The $int(A)$ is also $\mathbb{R}$, but this one I'm kind of guessing, as my thoughts: $A$ is an infinite set, the only open sets that contains $A$ is $\mathbb{R}$, but how do I show that this is the only open set?

Comment: For the closure you're right, but not for interior. You should look for the biggest open subset of $A$, not the smallest superset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve found $\operatorname{cl}A$ correctly, with correct reasoning, but you’ve gone badly astray with $\operatorname{int}A$. The interior of a set $S$ is always a *subset* of $S$: it’s the largest open set contained in $S$. Thus, $\operatorname{int}A$ cannot be $\Bbb R$, because $\Bbb R\nsubseteq A$. You know that the open sets in this space are $\varnothing$ and the complements of finite sets. If $\Bbb R\setminus U$ is finite, can $U$ be a subset of $A$?

Comment: oh, I messed up the definition. So open sets are {$\emptyset, \mathbb{R}$, and all the complements of finite sets}, $int(A)$ can't be $\mathbb{R}$ for $\mathbb{R}$ not contained in $A$, also, if $\mathbb{R} - U$ is finite, then $U$ is infinite, hence, can't contained in $A$ either, so the $int(A)$ must be the empty set

Comment: @Hobbit6094: Your conclusion is right, but part of your reasoning isn’t. The fact that $U$ is infinite isn’t enough to guarantee that $U\nsubseteq A$: $A$ is infinite, so it contains lots of infinite sets. The point is that $\Bbb R\setminus A$ is infinite, so if $U\subseteq A$, then $\Bbb R\setminus U\supseteq\Bbb R\setminus A$ is infinite, and therefore $U$ cannot be open – unless it’s empty.

Comment: oh, lol, thanks so much, not thinking thoroughly

Comment: @Hobbit6094: You’re welcome!